# Android Setting GridView Height

Tags: android, gridview, height

I have a GridView with variable height cells. I want the row to be as high as all the largest cell in the row. I am able to adjust the cell heights to be consistent on a row, but I cannot set the Height of the GridView and have it actually change.

Another problem is that this GridView is in a ScrollView, so having a scroll bar is out of the question.

This is a problem because the way the GridView determines the height of the entire Grid is to take the first cell and multiply it by the number of rows. This is an obvious problem if the rows can have different heights. For example:

[image: GridView auto height calc wrong]

I have tried numerous ways to update it, but I am sure I am missing something simple. I am trying to do the update in a ViewTreeObserver so I know that the GridView has rendered so my calcs are correct (and they are). The code:

```
        ViewTreeObserver treeListener = mGridView.getViewTreeObserver(); 
        treeListener.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override 
            public void onGlobalLayout() { 
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    mGridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } 
                else {
                    mGridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }

                // Calculate the new height we want for the GridView
                int newHeight = determineCellHeight(mGridView, mNumberOfColumns, mRows);

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mGridView.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = newHeight;
                mGridView.setLayoutParams(params);

                // Have tried all of these too!!!
//              mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//              mGridView.requestLayout();
//              mGridView.invalidateViews();
//              mGridView.refreshDrawableState();

//              mGridView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, newHeight + 10));
//              mGridView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, newHeight + 10)); 
//                 View lastChild = mGridView.getChildAt( mGridView.getChildCount() - 1 );
//                 mGridView.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, lastChild.getBottom() ) );
//                  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                  mGridView.invalidateViews();
//                  mGridView.setMinimumHeight(newHeight);
//                  mGridView.requestLayout();
//                  mGridView.refreshDrawableState();

            } 
        });
```

I am beginning to wonder if this is even possible, though the numerous Stackflows seem to suggest it is...

Answer (score 0):

I did come across this problem too several months ago, so there's an easy solution. You need to subclass your own GridView, and override the "onMeasure()" method so as to calculate the actual height of your needs. Here is the implementation.

```
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView {

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (isExpanded()) {
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.